# How to replace a Button's TextView with a custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-button

Instead of just a textview on a button, I'd like the button to contain a layout with two TextViews. See the mockup below. When a user uses the button to add a category, I'd like to update the percentage on the right. I have this working with an *included* layout, but I want to use a button so that the user instinctively knows to click it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Button is a `View` not a `ViewGroup`. To achieve that, use a horizontal LinearLayout, style it as a button and add a ClickListener to it. Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:text="Category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:text="value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that the background of the layout is set to the default android button so it will look like a button.

Comment: Almost what I need! It works, except that the button looks like a Gingerbread button on all Android versions. I haven't been able to find another drawable that appears correctly.

Comment: @NSouth Maybe create a style with `<item name="buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Button</item>
` and set the background to it will do trick.